# Using Onclick in object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
 <tr>
                <td class="timeHeader" id="timeInOutString"></td>
                <td id="timeControlHours"></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td id="timeControlMins"></td>
                <td onclick="this.TimeChangeView.AcceptTime()">Accept</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td onclick="this.TimeChangeView.downHours()">
```

Javascript:

```
function TimeChangeView(ac) {

    this.downHours = function(){


        //get element by Id

        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('timeControlHours').innerHTML);

        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value--;

        //add leading zeroes

        value = formatHoursMins(value);

        document.getElementById('timeControlHours').innerHTML = value;

    }




}
```

Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'downHours' of undefined

I have defined it in the script within a method called TimeChangeView, yet it is complaining that I have not defined it, why? Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn how the "this" word works. Google has many good articles about it index and ready for you.

Comment: The problem isn't `downHours`. Read the error message carefully. *Cannot call method 'downHours' of undefined*. `TimeChangeView` has a method called `downHours` but undefined doesn't. `this.TimeChangeView` returns undefined because `this` is `window`.

Comment: When I remove this it complains by saying uncaught TypeError: Object function TimeChangeView(ac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td onclick="this.TimeChangeView.downHours()">
```

You are calling the method `TimeChangeView` on the object `this`.

`this` refers to the object that the function is a method of. `TimeChangeView` is **not** a method of the object `this`, hence it does not work. (`this` is the `window` here)

You could *pass* `this` to  the function `TimeChangeView` like so: `TimeChangeView(this)`.

Read more about it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

### Update

To give you a better idea of how objects work in JavaScript, consider <kbd>[THIS CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/KRLz4/)</kbd>

As you can see, in the first function I call a method on the object:

```
button1.onclick=function()
{
    //Since we are calling a function on the object button1,
    //  in this function this = button1 (as an object)
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Hence `this` is in this case the object `button1`.

In the other function, I define a global function to which an object has to be passed:

```
function testFunction(passedObject)
{
    // In this function, we pass the object 'this' from button2
    // If I now call passedObject.id, it will give the id of the passed object
    // In this case that is 'button2'
    alert(passedObject.id);
}
```

In this function, there is no `this`. I can, however, pass an object to this function by calling `this` within an object in the HTML code.

E.g.:

```
<button id="button2" onclick="testFunction(this)">Button 2</button>
```

So now I call `testFunction(this)` and I pass the object `<button id="button2">Button 2</button>` as an argument.

So to summarize:

- Within an object, `this` refers to the object itself
- Outside an object, `this` refers to the nearest parent
- Within a method called upon an object, `this` refers to the object itself

A nice sentence to summarize this behaviour is:

*In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.*  [source](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: but are the js scripts not loaded into the browser window at run time? Thus this will reference the function?

Comment: Just think of `this` not as a static object but as a dependent reference to a changing object (depending on the scope). So don't think like it's Java ;)

Comment: right. When I remove it I just get the following error TypeError: Object function TimeChangeView(ac), any idea why?

Comment: Yes, `TimeChangeView(ac),` is expecting an argument `ac` as input when calling it. So calling it like `TimeChangeView()` is wrong.

Comment: Yeah - you see when I add TimeChangeView(this), it still complains. So I am not sure how to call that function directly. Sorry for all the questions, I am quite new to OOP in JS

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to call the apply/call method on the function TimeChangeView. The apply/call accepts two arguments the **this** object and any arguments that the function need (Note the second argument can be optional). For example we can then use it in this way TimeChangeView.apply(TimeChangeView) which sets the this value to TimeChangeView (Remember that function in JS is an object). You can also assign the TimeChangeView to a variable which you can use the variable to reference the functions inside TimeChangeView. Ex

var timeChangeView = TimeChangeView.apply(TimeChangeView);
<\td onclick="timeChangeView.downHours()">

You also need to return the **this** object inside the TimeChangeView function definition.